# How to create a type for reverse recursive reduce function?

Tags: typescript

First, sorry, it was really hard to define my question.

I have as string like this: `"first.second.third"` and some `value` (it can be object, boolean or string). I wrote `reduce` function which converts those two variables in object, it looks like this:

```js
{ first: { second: { third: value } } }
```

here is my function:

```js
const processNestedFilter = (columnField, value) => {
  const fields = columnField.split('.').reverse();
  const items = [value, ...fields];
  const nestedFilter = items.reduce((filter, current, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      return current;
    }
    return { [current]: filter };
  }, {});
  return nestedFilter;
};
```

I tried to write types for it, but failed. I'm not good yet with recursive type definitions in typescript. May someone explain, how you should start your type creation for such not simple functions? And could anyone help me with a type for it?

By reverse, I mean change of accumulator in reduce function to value and currentValue to key.

You may see how it works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-cache-wnlnuo?file=/src/index.js

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I don't understand. Value can be object, boolean or string, but you're using it as a key for an object. You can only use strings as keys for objects (unless you use arrays).

Comment: Your function doesn't behave as you describe; it outputs `{first:{second:{third:value}}}` and not `{third:{second:{first:value}}}`.  Please ensure that your code is a [mre] so people can help you; I can't tell if you want types for the regular or reverse version, since the code does something other than what your words seem to be saying.

Comment: @Kyle, boolean or object is always first value in array, so they got packed inside object, and never could be a key.

Comment: @jcalz, sorry, I fixed my example and wrote what I mean under 'reverse'.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WGPlXw) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we need to come with a description of what `processNestedFilter(columnField, value)` produces at the type level.  Let's call the type `ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>` and make it the return type of the function:

```
declare const processNestedFilter: <K extends string, V>(
  columnField: K, value: V) => ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>;
```

So `K` is the string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to `columnField`, like  `"first.second.third"` in your example; while `V` is the type corresponding to `value`.

---

We can write `ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>` as a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to split the `K` type at the dot character `"."`:

```
type ProcessNestedFilter<K extends string, V> =
  K extends `${infer F}.${infer R}` ?
  { [P in F]: ProcessNestedFilter<R, V> } : { [P in K]: V }
```

If `K` can be split into a first chunk `F`, followed by a dot `"."`, followed by the rest of the string `R`, then we want `ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>` to be an object type with `F` as a key, and whose value type is `ProcessNestedFilter<R, V>`.  We can write that as the [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) `{[P in F]: ProcessNestedFilter<R, V>}`; this is equivalent to `Record<F, ProcessNestedFilter<R, V>>` using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).

On the other hand, if `K` cannot be split this way, then it's a single key, and we want `ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>` to be an object type with `K` as a key and with `V` as a value.  We can write that as the mapped type `{[P in K]: V }`; this is equivalent to `Record<K, V>`.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const x = processNestedFilter("first.second.third", 123);
/* const x: {
    first: {
        second: {
            third: number;
        };
    };
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `x` is `{first: {second: {third: number}}}` as desired.

---

Note that the compiler cannot figure out that your implementation of `processNestedFilter` satisfies the call signature.  It's too complicated of a type function.  So you will need to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or something similar to convince the compiler not to warn you about the implementation.  That also means you need to be very careful to check that your implementation does what you say it does, because the compiler can't help.

It might look like this:

```
const processNestedFilter = <K extends string, V>(
  columnField: K, value: V) =>
  columnField.split('.').reverse().reduce<any>((filter, current) => {
    return { [current]: filter };
  }, value) as ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>;
```

Here I am saying that `reduce()` will produce [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) because I don't want the compiler to worry about it.  And then at the end I just assert that the return type is `ProcessNestedFilter<K, V>`.

And there you go:

```
console.log(x);
/* {
  "first": {
    "second": {
      "third": 123
    }
  }
} */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgewMYQM6oHJuBAJgMQEsAbHOAHgGkoIAPHAO11SlWDkIYHMAaKANQB8UALwAoKFGp1GzKAAMAJAG9OAMwhwo+AL4A6Fes1QASjvlQA-BKjKoAbRhRO2gLoAuWIhTosbPESkmuQmfEJQOlCedo7ODFIeAhFiYkgIDGxQYN5omNgBJGSiUFQ09BBMLGwc3GGCABQ2acQArgC2DEQQxLielHwAbgCGrRCe-ACUooJNCK0dXT16qGDEhMD1AOR6mxN6cBADmqgQ9XsHuC0o5EMMIA31aoWafEgtcAcMwFMiwso2kgOwHe8Ribw+FWAiSeQS0OgA3DYdIMRi0IFMhix4Mhcn4cARnhR+gJBIjUulMrRitkcb58gTYfUAERPOBsZYQNJMPTAAAWhDguCZfAAjAAmADME0RAHoAFRQLmU6IAqCstgqyRarUnLm9Wyq7XavkC-UMdoAI00iKNWoRqvtkTlMpSSrmED0xAQXHqtGlYnlBskLIFbCZmq1TN16SFEe1TJNgvDUHFEodSLETplQA)